# The absolute maximum of a function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{4+32x^{2}+x^{4}}-\sqrt{4+x^{4}}}{x}$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\neq 0$. Suppose that $f(x_{0})=M$ is the absolute maximum of $f$. Find $(x_{0},M)$.

I have no good ideas. It is not easy to solve the equation $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: I guess that's not that hard. After simplifying you'l get a nice equation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)<0$ for $x<0$. Since we are only interested in the maximum of $f(x)$, it suffices to consider $x>0$. Note that $x^4+4 \geq 4x^2$ with equality when $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$.

\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{4+32x^2+x^4}-\sqrt{4+x^4}}{x} &=\frac{32x^2}{x(\sqrt{4+32x^2+x^4}+\sqrt{4+x^4})} \\
& =\frac{32x}{\sqrt{4+32x^2+x^4}+\sqrt{4+x^4}} \\
& \leq \frac{32x}{\sqrt{32x^2+4x^2}+\sqrt{4x^2}} \\
& =4
\end{align}

Equality holds when $x=\sqrt{2}$, so we have $x_0=\sqrt{2}, M=4$.

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy but still simple.
So you have
$$\frac{x\frac{d\left(\sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^4+4}\right)}{dx}-\left(\sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^4+4}\right)}{x^2}=0$$
$$x\frac{d\left(\sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4}-\sqrt{x^4+4}\right)}{dx}=\frac{\left(4 x^4+64 x^2\right) \sqrt{x^4+4}-4 x^4 \sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4}}{2 \sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4} \sqrt{x^4+4}}$$
After collecting the terms  with roots you'l have:
$$\frac{\left(x^4-4\right) \left(\sqrt{x^4+4}-\sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4}\right)}{x^2 \sqrt{x^4+4} \sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4}}=0$$
You need to solve:

1. $\left(x^4-4\right)=0$ and get $\left\{\left\{x\to -\sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{x\to -i \sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{x\to i \sqrt{2}\right\},\left\{x\to \sqrt{2}\right\}\right\}$ And only 2 roots are real ($x\to \pm\sqrt{2}$).
2. And $\sqrt{x^4+4}-\sqrt{x^4+32 x^2+4}=0$ and get $x \to 0$, which is not the case we need, according to the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Show $\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x) = 0$, so you know there is a global $\max$ and $\min$. (Not that it matters, but $f$ is odd.)

$\frac{df(x)}{dx}= \frac{(x^2-2)(x^2+2)(\sqrt{x^4+4}-\sqrt{x^4+32 x^2 +4})}{x^2 \sqrt{x^4+4}\sqrt{x^4+32x^2+4}}$.

There are only two real stationary points. One must be the $\min$ and the other the $\max$.